# PowerShell/C# regex multiline replace returns wrong line ending

Tags: c#, regex, powershell, newline, multiline

I have a textfile with CRFL line endings, I read the whole file with
$c = Get-Content -Raw file.txt
the file contains e.g.

```
    exec Add a, b, c
    exec Rem e, f, g
```

I try to replace it with my regex
$c = $c -replace '(?m)^([ \t]*)(@exec@)([ \t]+)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(.*)$' '$1call$3$4($5)'
This doesn't work and I don't know why but to get it working I need to run
$c = $c -replace '(?m)^([ \t]*)(@exec@)([ \t]+)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(.*)\r\n?$' '$1call$3$4($5)'
and the result is

```
    call Add(a, b, c
)
    exec Rem(e, f, g
)
```

with a LF after the ) bracket.
I would expect to get

```
    call Add(a, b, c)
    exec Rem(e, f, g)
```

with CRLFs

What's wrong with PowerShell and $ and CRLF?
Can anybody tell me how to get the correct results?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the "bug" and a solution. The $ at the end is not working with MS regex

```
(?m)^...\r\n
```

This works

Answer (score 0):

I could not get your regex to match anything but this more generic replace should do the trick:

```
-replace  '(?m)^(\s*)([^\s]*)(\s*)([^\s]*)(\s*)(.*)$', '$1call$3$4$5($6)'
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check my example.
I've tried your example and it produces the wrong output as I described with only a LF instead or CRLF

Comment: If you skip the -raw option in get-content powershell makes any line endings CRLF. Seems that your inputfile might have a LF CRLF mix.